# how to use paging in new graph facebook v4

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I have tried the code below but I am getting an error.How can I use paging in v4 facebook after/within login?

```
// Callback registration
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {


GraphRequest request2 = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(
                                        JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {

                                    JSONObject  uu= response.getJSONObject();
                                    if (uu!=null){
                                        Log.w(TAG, "respomse: " + response.toString());

                                    }


 GraphRequest nextPageRequest = response.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
                if (nextPageRequest != null) {             
                nextPageRequest.setCallback(new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                }
                });


                                                       nextPageRequest.executeBatchAsync(
                }
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters2 = new Bundle();
                    parameters2.putString("fields", "likes");
                    parameters2.putString("limit", "999");
                    request2.setParameters(parameters2);
                    request2.executeAsync();

   });

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I have updated the code above and its giving error hereFacebookCallback<LoginResult>() .It has to implement methods but onerror() and onCancel() is already implemented.How to fix that ?

Comment: Your formatting is off which makes it hard to read the code, can you get your IDE to format it before you post? Can you also paste the compiler error as is?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code within my `User` class. Every time a new user signs up using Facebook, this gets executed by calling `get_user_data()` within the `User` constructor.

For the below example to work for you too, you'll need an access token with the following permissions:

1. `user_friends`
2. `email`

**Constants**:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap> user_fb_friends;

private final String FIELDS = "id,first_name,last_name,name,gender,locale,timezone,updated_time,email,link,picture,friends{id,first_name,last_name,name,gender,updated_time,link,picture}";
private final String USER_FB_ID_TAG = "id";
private final String F_NAME_TAG = "first_name";
private final String L_NAME_TAG = "last_name";
private final String FULL_NAME_TAG = "name";
private final String GENDER_TAG = "gender";
private final String LOCALE_TAG = "locale";
private final String TIMEZONE_TAG = "timezone";
private final String UPDATED_TIME_TAG = "updated_time";
private final String EMAIL_TAG = "email";
private final String LINK_TAG = "link";
private final String PICTURE_TAG = "picture";
private final String DATA_TAG = "data";
private final String IS_SILHOUETTE_TAG = "is_silhouette";
private final String URL_TAG = "url";
private final String FRIENDS_TAG = "friends";
private final String PAGING_TAG = "paging";
private final String NEXT_TAG = "next";
private final String SUMMARY_TAG = "summary";
private final String TOTAL_COUNT_TAG = "total_count";
```

**Actual code:**

(the following code includes local setters)

```
private void get_user_data(){

    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            Signup_fragment.mAccessToken,
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                    JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                    if(json != null){
                        try {
                            user_fb_friends = new ArrayList<>();

                            /*
                             * Start parsing the JSON
                             * 1. Pars the user personal details and save them on new User class
                             */

                            setUser_fb_id(json.getString(USER_FB_ID_TAG));
                            setF_name(json.getString(F_NAME_TAG));
                            setL_name(json.getString(L_NAME_TAG));
                            setFull_name(json.getString(FULL_NAME_TAG));
                            setGender(json.getString(GENDER_TAG));
                            setLocale(json.getString(LOCALE_TAG));
                            setTimezone(json.getInt(TIMEZONE_TAG));
                            setUpdated_time((Date) json.get(UPDATED_TIME_TAG));
                            setEmail(json.getString(EMAIL_TAG));
                            setFb_profile_link(json.getString(LINK_TAG));
                            Utils.log("User prsonal data was collected (" + getFull_name() + ")");
                            JSONObject pic_wrapper = json.getJSONObject(PICTURE_TAG);
                            JSONObject pic_data = pic_wrapper.getJSONObject(DATA_TAG);
                            if(!pic_data.getBoolean(IS_SILHOUETTE_TAG)){
                                setFb_profile_pic_link(pic_data.getString(URL_TAG));
                            }

                            /*
                             * 2. Go over the jsonArry of friends, pars and save each friend
                             * in a HashMap object and store it in user_fb_friends array
                             */

                            JSONObject friends_wrapper = json.getJSONObject(FRIENDS_TAG);
                            JSONArray friends_json_array = friends_wrapper.getJSONArray(DATA_TAG);
                            if(friends_json_array.length() > 0){

                                for (int i = 0; i < friends_json_array.length(); i++) {
                                    HashMap<String, String> friend_hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    JSONObject friend_json = friends_json_array.getJSONObject(i);

                                    friend_hashmap.put(USER_FB_ID_TAG, friend_json.getString(USER_FB_ID_TAG));
                                    friend_hashmap.put(F_NAME_TAG, friend_json.getString(F_NAME_TAG));
                                    friend_hashmap.put(L_NAME_TAG, friend_json.getString(L_NAME_TAG));
                                    friend_hashmap.put(FULL_NAME_TAG, friend_json.getString(FULL_NAME_TAG));
                                    friend_hashmap.put(GENDER_TAG, friend_json.getString(GENDER_TAG));
                                    friend_hashmap.put(UPDATED_TIME_TAG, friend_json.getString(UPDATED_TIME_TAG));
                                    friend_hashmap.put(LINK_TAG, friend_json.getString(LINK_TAG));
                                    JSONObject friend_pic_wrapper = json.getJSONObject(PICTURE_TAG);
                                    JSONObject friend_pic_data = friend_pic_wrapper.getJSONObject(DATA_TAG);
                                    if(!friend_pic_data.getBoolean(IS_SILHOUETTE_TAG)){
                                        friend_hashmap.put(URL_TAG, friend_pic_data.getString(URL_TAG));
                                    }
                                    user_fb_friends.add(friend_hashmap);
                                    Utils.log("A friend was added to user_fb_friends (" + i + ")");
                                }

                                /*
                                 * 3. Get the URL for the next "friends" JSONObject and send
                                 * a GET request
                                 */

                                JSONObject paging_wrapper = json.getJSONObject(PAGING_TAG);
                                String next_friends_json_url = null;
                                if(paging_wrapper.getString(NEXT_TAG) != null){
                                    next_friends_json_url = paging_wrapper.getString(NEXT_TAG);
                                }
                                JSONObject summary_wrapper = json.getJSONObject(SUMMARY_TAG);
                                int total_friends_count = summary_wrapper.getInt(TOTAL_COUNT_TAG);

                                if(next_friends_json_url != null){
                                    /*
                                     * Send a GET request for the next JSONObject
                                     */
                                    get_paging_data(response);
                                }
                            } else {
                                Utils.log("friends_json_array == null");
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", FIELDS);
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}

private void get_paging_data(GraphResponse response){

    GraphRequest nextRequest = response.getRequestForPagedResults(GraphResponse.PagingDirection.NEXT);
    Utils.log("get_paging_data was called");
    nextRequest.setCallback(new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray friends_json_array = json.getJSONArray(DATA_TAG);

                    for (int i = 0; i < friends_json_array.length(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> friend_hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject friend_json = friends_json_array.getJSONObject(i);

                        friend_hashmap.put(USER_FB_ID_TAG, friend_json.getString(USER_FB_ID_TAG));
                        friend_hashmap.put(F_NAME_TAG, friend_json.getString(F_NAME_TAG));
                        friend_hashmap.put(L_NAME_TAG, friend_json.getString(L_NAME_TAG));
                        friend_hashmap.put(FULL_NAME_TAG, friend_json.getString(FULL_NAME_TAG));
                        friend_hashmap.put(GENDER_TAG, friend_json.getString(GENDER_TAG));
                        friend_hashmap.put(UPDATED_TIME_TAG, friend_json.getString(UPDATED_TIME_TAG));
                        friend_hashmap.put(LINK_TAG, friend_json.getString(LINK_TAG));
                        JSONObject friend_pic_wrapper = json.getJSONObject(PICTURE_TAG);
                        JSONObject friend_pic_data = friend_pic_wrapper.getJSONObject(DATA_TAG);
                        if (!friend_pic_data.getBoolean(IS_SILHOUETTE_TAG)) {
                            friend_hashmap.put(URL_TAG, friend_pic_data.getString(URL_TAG));
                        }
                        user_fb_friends.add(friend_hashmap);
                        Utils.log("A friend was added to user_fb_friends (" + i + ")");
                    }

                    JSONObject paging_wrapper = json.getJSONObject(PAGING_TAG);
                    String next_friends_json_url = null;
                    if (paging_wrapper.getString(NEXT_TAG) != null) {
                        next_friends_json_url = paging_wrapper.getString(NEXT_TAG);
                    }
                    JSONObject summary_wrapper = json.getJSONObject(SUMMARY_TAG);

                    if (next_friends_json_url != null) {
                        /*
                         * 3. Send a GET request for the next JSONObject
                         */
                        get_paging_data(response);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    response = nextRequest.executeAndWait();
}
```

Before you go ahead and try to pars your JSON, first check what your JSON will look like. You can check that using Facebook's Graph Explorer at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

**IMPORTANT**: Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher. total_count in summary represents the total number of friends, including those who haven't installed the app. [More >>](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0)

Comment: My code is similar to yours but on executing request for next page, it gives NetworkOnMainThreadException. Any idea on that?